# Make changes over buttons send to a QSignalMapper in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

This is a `for` loop of the code positioning and giving sizes to 22 buttons:

```
for(int i=0; i<texts.size(); ++i)
      {
         QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(texts[i]);

        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
                signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
         button -> setFixedSize(50,30);

        signalMapper -> setMapping(button, texts[i]);
         gridLayout -> addWidget(button, i/5, i%5);
      }
```

The image of the output is as the following:

[image]

I want to manipulate the `size`, `position`, `color` and `font` of each button "manually". I think I need to somehow take back the buttons from `signalMapper` so that I will be able to do these works on them. Do you agree?
What is the simplest and most straight forward way to do those works please?

PS: I wrote the app only in *C++ code* and didn't use the *Designer*.

Comment: why don't you [`setStyleSheet()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)/[`setPalette()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop) on the button before adding it to the layout? Maybe have another array for styleSheets/Palettes and use it in your loop along with your `texts` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each button with the mapping function:

```
QPushButton* button = static_cast<QPushButton*>(this->siganlMapper.mapping("1"));
button->setStyleSheet("color: red");
```

This will change the text color of the button with the number 1 to red

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `QList<QPuchButton>` to dynamically store all of your button in. Do this while they're being created. It will en up something like this:

```
QList<QPushButton*> calcButtons;//QList for storing the buttons
    for(int i=0; i<texts.size(); ++i)
    {
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(texts[i]);
        calcButtons << button;
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
                signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        button -> setFixedSize(50,30);

        signalMapper -> setMapping(button, texts[i]);
        gridLayout -> addWidget(button, i/5, i%5);
    }

    calcButtons[0];//Use this to access them later. '0' being the first button added.
```