# QSignalMapper problems with strings

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I have a question about QSignalMapper.

I have simple application, a calculator. And I have something like this, I click button and I want to display it. But I have problem, I don't know how to assign string to a button. It only want to work with integers. But i know it is possible to do it with strings. And I need to do it on strings, because then I want to convert it to double type. I have idea how do rest of things I want to do, but this QSignalMapper is killing me.

```
QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(ui->Button0, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->Button0, '0');
```

I tried to do something with QString but it did not help.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? I am 90% sure you don't need `QSignalMapper` for that, but I need more details to show the solution. Also, what exactly does not work with your current approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need signalMapper to accomplish what you are looking for. A standard connect() function call will likely work.

1. [Try using Qt5 syntax for creating the connection](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)
2. Change your connect function call to include units if you are using the old way.

**Edited - Example syntax for connect**

> New way. Note that param datatypes are not included in the connect
> call.
>
> ```
> connect(
>     sender, &Sender::valueChanged,
>     receiver, &Receiver::updateValue
> );
> ```
>
> Old way
>
> ```
> connect(
>     sender, SIGNAL( valueChanged( QString, QString ) ),
>     receiver, SLOT( updateValue( QString ) )
> );
> ```

**Edited - Method 1 --> Using two known C++ objs**

1. Create a signal function emitting a QString
2. Create a slot function recieving a QString
3. Connect the two QStrings together
4. Handle as desired

**Edited - Method 2 --> [Using QML exclusively](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)**

1. Declare signal(string str) in QML
2. Use existing btn onClicked event and call declared signal
3. Handle to signal via slot and do as needed with text

**Edited - Method 3 --> [Use QSignalMapper if dealing with MVC and indexs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910401/make-changes-over-buttons-send-to-a-qsignalmapper-in-qt)**

[1. See Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html)

2. Use lambda method to connect button click and text

> connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, text] { clicked(text);
> });

[image: QSignal Mapper Lambda]

Hopefully one of these methods provides some help to solving your problem!

Comment: I don't see how `valueChanged(QString, QString)` corresponds to `QPushButton::clicked(bool)`

Comment: Sorry, I was providing an example. I will update the example to fit the users needs.

Comment: Thank You for help. Stupid to say it but I just had error in the name of the function I was referring to. I need to do it in two files, where in one is all the logic of calculator and in the second one are connection. I'm doing it like this. I click on the button and it shows on the display, and it is string type, then it is converted to a double type, then when I click on operation button like adding I use boolean variable to check is there any value on the left side of equation, if it is true I can type value of right side and click equal. My teacher want me to do it like this...